# xrandr unable to set Broadcast RGB

Tags: networking, display, xrandr

Can anyone help me with this? I was trying to use xrandr to fix the washed out colors on Ubuntu (macOS doesn't have this issue for me) but it sort of just returned:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  11 (RRQueryOutputProperty)
  Serial number of failed request:  42
  Current serial number in output stream:  42
```

This is the command I was trying to use:

```
xrandr --output LVDS-1 --set "Broadcast RGB" "Full"
```

I'm currently on a Macbook Pro mid 2012 "13

Comment: You've provided no OS & release details which are a starting point (Xorg isn't default for some recent release(s); so `xrandr` can have limits if X isn't being used directly)

Comment: As per the other comment, I would suggest you ensure you are running Ubuntu on Xorg and not Wayland. Some things just don't work with Wayland and Wayland has been made default since 21.04. See here for instructions/details: https://itsfoss.com/switch-xorg-wayland/

Comment: @codlord I'm sorry for forgetting to mention that. Yes I'm running Xorg and I'm on PopOS 21.04 (which I guess, is close enough to Ubuntu)

Comment: I suggest you update your original question with the full result of running just `xrandr`

Comment: Only Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use the Pop forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu & flavors are the many support options, you opted for Pop OS so take advantage of it's support options, or SE Unix & Linux*)

Comment: @guiverc Alright, I'll try asking out on other forums. Thanks for the help